# Set up the form of GroupMessage model on the page of group/show/:id(view)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

1.I would like to set up the form of GroupMessage model on the view page, group/show/:id.

2.I tried the code below.

**(show.html.erb-group)**

```
<%= form_for([@group, @group_messages]) do |f| %>
<% if @group_message.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@group_message.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this group_message    from being saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% @group_message.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :member_id %><br />
<%= f.number_field :member_id %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :content %><br />
<%= f.text_area :content %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div> 
<% end %>
```

**(groups_controller)**

```
def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @group_message = @group.group_messages.build
    if !checklogin? then return end
        groupfriends = GroupInMember.where(:member_id => session[:login].id)
         gflist = '('
        groupfriends.each do |gf|
         gflist += gf.member_id.to_s + ","
        end
      gflist += session[:login].id.to_s + ')'
       @query = "select * from group_messages where member_id in " +  gflist 
       @group_messages = GroupMessage.find_by_sql(@query)
respond_to do |format|
format.html # index.html.erb
format.json { render json: @group_messages }
end
end
```

3.And then I got an error.
undefined method `group_messages' for #

4.How can I solve this??

Comment: Does your model's have relationship?

Comment: You are right. I forgot to put relationships between Group and GroupMessage. In addition to that, I added the column "group_id" to GroupMessage. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `@group = Group.find(params[:id])` is not returning a `Group`.